# C++ Continuing from 'else' statement

Tags: c++

I'm writing a little c++ console program to improve my programming and to begin a portfolio. My question is:

How do I continue my story after the `else` statement?

Part of the code I have is:

```
else {
    cout << "That's not an answer mate!" << endl;
}
```

How do I make the program **NOT** exit, but ask for a **new input** from the user?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: use `while`

Comment: Start to use structured programming. You are thinking in terms of "go to X, then go to Y, then go to Z". You need *loops*. Every introductory book on programming covers loops.

Comment: You my friend, are a smart person. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You wrap the qustioning code in a `while` and keep asking until the "correct" answer is given:

```
bool error;
do {
  error = false;
  //some code here..
  //if statement to check..
  else
  {
    cout << "That's not an answer mate!" << endl;
    error = true;
  }
}while(error);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `goto` statement 
example:

```
Condition1: cout<<"Enter age: ";
cin>>age;

if (age>18){
cout<<"Welcome"<<endl;
//same code...
}
else{
goto Condition1;
}
```

this is the same method as using loops

Comment: Advising to use goto to a beginner. You must be joking

Comment: I have to agree with @MuhammetAliAsan on this one - goto is a *terrible* practice.

Comment: Noted with thanks... @Muhammet Ali Asan , cc @ EJoshuaS